# PHP SwiftMailer Localhost Test Setup

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I just started learning how to use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and I am having trouble sending a simple test message from my localhost. Below is the code that I am trying to use.

```
//Pass it as a parameter when you create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject('My subject');
$message->setFrom(array('noreply@domain.com' => 'No Reply'));
$message->setTo(array('myemail@domain.com' => 'My Name'));

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 25);
//Supposed to allow local domain sending to work from what I read
$transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
//Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Here is part of my error message,

```
Warning:  fsockopen() [<a href='function.fsockopen'>function.fsockopen</a>]:php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /path/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
```

**Update**

I got it to work using gmail. I changed the Swift_SmtpTransport line to the following,

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('username')->setPassword('password');
```

Comment: this line worked for me too using gmail account

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localhost` is an alias for current machine (in this case, the machine PHP runs on). If you really want to send mail with localhost you have say so:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25);
```

... but you also need to install and configure your own mail server. If you don't know what's this all about, I suggest you use your mail provider's SMTP server.

Comment: Ok so I am altering my code to use Gmails smtp....Can you tell me how to setup the SSL info through SwiftMailer to get this working? I also need to add the username/password somewhere.

Comment: Cool, I added the ssl string to the constructor and it worked! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm testing from localhost as I setup a webapp I'm writing and $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance('localhost', 25); got it working for me

Comment: very helpful, Thank You!